# Django Pickle Field Access to its model instance on load

Tags: python, django, pickle

I have a custom django field subclass for storing my own pickled classes. Is there any way I could set a `model` attribute that points to the model **instance** on my **pickled** class on each load from the database?

So far my best guess is in the unpickling process, inside the `to_python` method, but I'm not sure if the `Field` has a reference to the model *instance* or *class*.

**EDIT 1:** The model reference inside of the `to_python` method is indeed a reference to the *class*, not the *instance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I overrode the model's `__init__` method like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't do any extra looping or anything in here because this gets called
        # at least once for every row in each query of this table
        self._meta.fields[2].model_instance = self
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.PickleField()
    field3 = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then in my field subclass:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    # logic and unpickling, then right before your return:
    if hasattr(self, 'model_instance'): # avoid AttributeError if list, dict, etc.
        value.model_instance = self.model_instance
    return value
```